# How can I capture the word over which a right click is made in GTK?

Tags: c, gtk

I have a `GtkTextView` widget and I want to display a custom popup menu when the user right-clicks on a word. In order to display the appropriate menu, I need to know what word is located at that position.

Like the following:
[image]

I'm reading the docs but I haven't found the way yet.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got it working by connecting the `button-press-event` signal from `GtkTextView` to the function that creates the menu

```
g_signal_connect(text_view, "button-press-event", G_CALLBACK(right_click_menu), NULL);
```

the function handling the menu creation will ignore the event when it's not generated by the button expected (right-click)

```
if(event->button.button != 3)
    return FALSE;
```

getting the word is just a matter of calling `gtk_text_view_window_to_buffer_coords` with the coordinates that were passed in with the `GdkEvent`

```
int x, y;
gtk_text_view_window_to_buffer_coords(  GTK_TEXT_VIEW(text_view),
                                        GTK_TEXT_WINDOW_WIDGET,
                                        event->button.x,
                                        event->button.y,
                                        &x,
                                        &y                      );
```

and asking for an iterator with

```
GtkTextIter iter;
gtk_text_view_get_iter_at_location(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(text_view), &iter, x, y);
```

then using the `GtkTextIter` functions (https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTextIter.html) to determine the word bounds.

Answer (score 1):

GTK+ uses the Pango library for it's text layouting. The Pango API provides the function `pango_layout_xy_to_index()` which when given an co-ordinate inside the layout will provide you with the **byte** index into the text that the layout was created for.

With this information you can identify the word that the given character is inside by searching forwards/backwards for the appropriate punctuation.

If you are using `GtkEntry` as your widget then to translate the mouse co-ordinates from the click into layout co-ordinates then will need to use `gtk_entry_get_layout_offsets()` to retrieve the position of the layout relative to the widget.